# In embedded application why c is most poppular?

Tags: c, linux, embedded

see ,

still yet i have seen that most of the **embedded application** are written in c. 
Most of the libraries are written in c. 
Device-driver are written in c.

So i want to ask you is there any logical reason behind this?

(My apologies if this post sounds silly/stupid. I thought I'd ask here. Ignoring these core bits never made anyone a better programmer.)

Comment: This is because young programmers don't know Ada.

Comment: This is mostly down to reasons of history.

Comment: You can find hundreds of articles and debates on this very topic if you Google it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many reasons, including but not limited to:

- It has access to many low level functions not accessible from many other languages.
- It has existed for many many years and has lots of developers that are familiar with it.
- If written well it's extremely efficient.
- It gives almost complete control over memory etc.
- It's very portable, largely due to the myriad of compilers written for it.

Comment: Plus the footprint is smaller than C++, and the code is compiled not interpreted (vs Java)

Comment: Yeah there are loads of things that can be added to the list. I just picked a few off the top of my head to be honest.

Comment: I was just collaborating, not criticizing ;)

Comment: I know, that's why I 'up'ed your comment. ;)

Comment: In addition, all flaws and pitfalls of C are well-known, and you can easily avoid them by using a safe subset like MISRA-C or similar.

Answer (score 2):

Because of Dennis Ritchie. C is easily the most portable language.

Comment: +1 ! Many embedded platforms, so the C portability is definetely a big plus !